# Trying to return the index of the of the parent array with the highest value object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am following a Udemy JavaScript Course and am revisiting all the coding exercises in ES6.

I have an array of teams. Each team with in the array is an object. I would like to compare them and return the winner, however, my aim is to do this in a scaleable way (should I want to add more teams in future).

Below is the code I have so far. I would like it to evaluate any number of arrays. The issue I face is that it will only evaluate the first two arrays.

```
class Team {
    constructor(teamName, scores) {
    this.teamName = teamName,
    this.scores = scores;
    this.avgScore = Math.floor(this.scores.reduce((prev, cur) => (prev + cur) / this.scores.length));
    }
}
 
// Generate some random scores
randomNumber = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 250);
randomScore = () => [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()];
 
// Create the teams
let teams = [
    new Team('Team John', randomScore()),
    new Team('Team Mike', randomScore()),
    new Team('Team Mary', randomScore())
]

 
// so I can debug
for (el of teams) {
    console.log(`${el.teamName}: ${el.avgScore}`)
}

// attempt to make this scalable
let winner = 0;
calcWinner = () => teams.reduce((prev, cur, index) => cur.avgScore > prev.avgScore ? winner = index : winner = winner);
calcWinner();
 
// More debug
console.log(winner);
 
// Log result to the console
console.log(`The team with the highest average is ${teams[winner].teamName}, with a score of ${teams[winner].avgScore}`)
```

Comment: A side issue: You're not calculating averages correctly.  It should be `this.avgScore = Math.floor(this.scores.reduce((prev, cur) => (prev + cur)) / this.scores.length);` (I moved the division out of the `reduce` call.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks! I would have never spotted that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got couple of things wrong here:

1. Average calculation:

> ```
> this.avgScore = Math.floor(this.scores.reduce((total, current) => (total + current)) / this.scores.length);
> ```

2. This should be code to filter highest average team:

> ```
> let winner = team[0];
> teams.forEach(team => {
>   if(team.avgScore > winner.avgScore ) {
>     winner = team; 
>   }
> });
>
> colsole.log(`Team name: ${winner.teamName} , Average Score: ${winner.avgScore}`)
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It is good to see an alternative to my use of the reduce method. I had thought about forEach but just could not wrap my head around the logic. Happy to say I can see why this works though :)

Answer (score 0):

You were not setting and returning prev(highest score) in reduce method. First, initialize prev to zero in reduce method. Then put the highest score into prev if cur.avgScore is greater than prev. This is the syntax of **array.reduce**:
*array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)*

```js
class Team {
  constructor(teamName, scores) {
    (this.teamName = teamName), (this.scores = scores);
    this.avgScore = Math.floor(
      this.scores.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur) / this.scores.length
    );
  }
}

// Generate some random scores
randomNumber = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 250);
randomScore = () => [randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber()];

// Create the teams
let teams = [
  new Team("Team John", randomScore()),
  new Team("Team Mike", randomScore()),
  new Team("Team Mary", randomScore()),
];

// so I can debug
for (el of teams) {
  console.log(`${el.teamName}: ${el.avgScore}`);
}

// attempt to make this scalable
let winner = 0;
calcWinner = () =>
  teams.reduce((prev, cur, index) => {
    if (cur.avgScore > prev) {
      winner = index;
      prev = cur.avgScore;
    }
    return prev;
  }, 0);
calcWinner();

// More debug
console.log(winner);

// Log result to the console
console.log(
  `The team with the highest average is ${teams[winner].teamName}, with a score of ${teams[winner].avgScore}`
);
```

Comment: This solved it! Thank you for the explanation. Looks like I need to do some further reading on the reduce method. Very much appreciated